# aid at installing a cms of laravel again with empty database

Tags: php, laravel

Hello guys i want to reinstall an old cms of a friend which is on laravel 5.1.* but this time i don't have the database and i just have migration files and when i run php artisan migrate every thing goes fun except i get weird error s while trying to visit home page and cant login as super user like below

```
Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\wamp64\www\cms\resources\views . . . .
```

i would wonder if can any one help with this and i can even share the source of the code with you to try it on your local system . thanks very much in advance .

Comment: just forgot to say mention your email and i send the files for you if you are intrested in this and just to say its a very complete cms and you can keep the source also for your self .

Comment: Migration generally only set up the database structure/tables, and do not fill them with data the application may rely on. It sounds like you're missing the data.

Comment: If your application has any seeders, you could make use of `php artisan migrate:refresh --seed` to populate your db with seeder data.

Comment: @linktoahref unfortunately it doesn't have any seeder just tried that but nothing .i am looking for some one with laravel knowledge to see if is it possible at all to run this with raw database or with feeling necessary data

Comment: @EmilePels yes exactly and i wounder to see if any one can feel the data with necessary data which are most to run

Comment: @user3357687 Nobody can "guess" what data is supposed to be there...

Comment: You could easily write your own user seeder if all you need in an admin account..